# Make div's below each other

Tags: css, reactjs

I have this React code:

```
const AddPlace = () => {
  return (
    <div className="split">
        <div className="left">
            <AddPlaceCard />
        </div>
        <div className="right" id="map">
            <Map />
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

for large screens this is my CSS:

```
.split {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: raw;
}

.left {
  width: 50%;
}

.right {
  width: 50%;
}
```

Large Screen Image:
[image]

Now I want a responsive design for mobile which orders the map below the card, I used this code but it didn't help:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .split {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .left {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .right {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Small Screen Image:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get away from explicitly setting widths and just use `flex grow:1` for each of the child divs - to see the difference - view the snippet in the small snippet window for the small view - and then click the toggle fullScreen button to see the divs sit side by side.

So to explain the code - in both scenarios = the flex-grow: 1 on the child divs causes it to expand to fill the available space - and because there are two divs - this will cause a 50% / 50% split (same deal if there are 3 divs - they will take up equal thirds of the available space).

So the only difference then between the normal and the media-query is which direction do they grow in. Since the default direction is "row" you do not really even need to include that in the initial styling - I included it to demontrate the point in this snippet.

In flex direction: row: - flex-grow: 1 will cause a horizontal expansiosion and in flex-direction: column - it is a vertical expansion.

Also - note that by applying height: 100% to the html, body, and .split - each div takes the entire height available.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  margin:0
}

.split {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 100%;
}

.split div {
  flex-grow:1;
  padding: 16px
}

.left {
  border: solid 1px red;
}

.right {
  border: solid 1px blue;

}



@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .split {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="split">
    <div class="left">
         <p> This is the div for the placecard</p>
    </div>
    <div class="right" id="map">
        <p> This is the div for the map</p>
    </div>
</div>
```